# Are there any tricks to reduce memory usage when storing String data type in hashmap?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I need to store value pair (word and number) in the Map.

I am trying to use `TObjectIntHashMap` from Trove library with `char[]` as the key, because I need to minimize the memory usage. But with this method, I can not get the value when I use `get()` method.
I guess I can not use primitive char array to store in a Map because hashcode issues.

I tried to use `TCharArrayList` but that takes much memory also.
I read in another stackoverflow question that similar with my purpose and have suggestion to use `TLongIntHashMap` , store encode values of String word in long data type. In this case my words may contains of latin characters or various other characters that appears in wikipedia collections, I do not know whether the Long is enough for encode or not.

I have tried using Trie data structure to store it, but I need to consider my performance also and choose the best for both memory usage and performance.

Do you have any idea or suggestion for this issue?

Comment: Do the 'words' have any special characteristics? For example, are they actually a bunch of URLs?

Comment: you can use String because 1) it's immutable and hence best candidate for a hash key as to avoid collisions 2)it's internally uses char[] array as you require.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga since the words has passed stemming and filtering unnecessary words, I think there is no URLs.

Comment: @Arham yes, that is the best way to use String directly, but I try to reduce memory usage because I faced with huge number of words for my dictionary. I have read some articles about the memory usage for String and It said that we could reduce String itself by using substring of the original String. I am trying to use it but I have not found any difference (or may be I do memory calculation incorrectly). btw thanks for your advice.

Comment: @novita if you are doing String str2 = str1.substring(x,y), then there is no memory reduction because it's only changing the start pointer of str1 to x and the length to y-x+1. But internally String str2 is referring to the same string str1.

Comment: @Arham I read this articles [link](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml) and I tried to do like that example: str1 = new String(str1.substring(x,y)). But I still do not understand if I put on that new string on map which has String as key, then the string that inserted to map is reduced or not.

Comment: you shouldn't change a string which is already serving as a key to a map. because then you are breaking the hashcode value of the key which was based on the previous value of the string.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the most compact way to store the data is to use a `byte[]` encoded in `UTF-8` or similar.  You can wrap this in your own class or write you own HashMap which allows byte[] as a key.

I would reconsider how much time it is worth spending to save some memory. If you are talking about a PC or Server, at minimum wage you need to save 1 GB for an hours work so if you are only looking to save 100 MB that's about 6 minutes including testing.

Comment: @Peter_Lawrey - Although considering the effort-to-reward ratio is important, I don't think you should be telling other any specific formula or ratio; Such definitions are subjective, as they vary with individual opinion, and how critical memory-saving is for the project. --- With this in mind, you even talk more about it than the actual answer. How about explaining why `byte[]` encoded with `UTF-8` would be more efficient instead? While keeping just *I would reconsider how much time it is worth spending to save some memory.* for the effort-to-reward part.

Comment: Java's Strings use a variant of the UC2/UTF-16 in memory. That means every ASCII character incurs 2 bytes of memory use. If the words being stored here tend to have characters with codepoints below U+128, i.e. ASCII 0..127, then, UTF-8 encoding can reduce the memory used to store the actual characters by 50%. Note that the actual outer object and the array incur some fixed cost per instance, in the 2 x (8 - 20 byte) range.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own class that implements `CharSequence`, and write your own implementation of `equals()` and `hashcode()`. The implementation would also pre-allocate large shared `char[]` storage, and use bits of it at a time. (You can definitely incorporate @Peter Lawrey's excellent suggestion into this, too, and use `byte[]` storage.)

There's also an opportunity to do a 'soft intern()' using an LRU cache. I've noted where the cache would go.

Here's a simple demonstration of what I mean. Note that if you need heavily concurrent writes, you can try to improve the locking scheme below...

```
public final class CompactString implements CharSequence {
  private final char[] _data;
  private final int _offset;
  private final int _length;
  private final int _hashCode;

  private static final Object _lock = new Object();
  private static char[] _storage;
  private static int _nextIndex;

  private static final int LENGTH_THRESHOLD = 128;

  private CompactString(char[] data, int offset, int length, int hashCode) {
    _data = data; _offset = offset; _length = length; _hashCode = hashCode;
  }

  private static final CompactString EMPTY = new CompactString(new char[0], 0, 0, "".hashCode());

  private static allocateStorage() {
    synchronized (_lock) {
      _storage = new char[1024];
      _nextIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  private static CompactString storeInShared(String value) {
    synchronized (_lock) {
      if (_nextIndex + value.length() > _storage.length) {
        allocateStorage();
      }
      int start = _nextIndex; 
      // You would need to change this loop and length to do UTF encoding.
      for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); ++i) {
        _storage[_nextIndex++] = value.charAt(i);
      }
      return new CompactString(_storage, start, value.length(), value.hashCode());
    }
  }

  static {
    allocateStorage();
  }

  public static CompactString valueOf(String value) {
    // You can implement a soft .intern-like solution here.
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    } else if (value.length() == 0) {
      return EMPTY;
    } else if (value.length() > LENGTH_THRESHOLD) {
      // You would need to change .toCharArray() and length to do UTF encoding.
      return new CompactString(value.toCharArray(), 0, value.length(), value.hashCode());
    } else {
      return storeInShared(value);
    }
  }

  // left to reader: implement equals etc.
}
```

Comment: I have tried some kind of compact string which is similar with your code above(without hashcode). When I want to put my string in a Map, I call my compactString function to create a new String. I tried that approach using TObjectIntHashMap with the key is String. is it a correct way to call compact string function before put my string on the map? how could we prove that it works well (takes less memory)? Thank you for your sample code above, I would have alook and try it, Thank you in advanced.